# Unable to close the DateTimePickerModal after setting the time in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I am learning to set the time in ReactNative.
I was able to set the time with the onConfirm process of DateTimePickerModal, but I am having trouble closing the DateTimePicker at the same time.
Here is the source.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import{
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
}from 'react-native';
//import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-    community/datetimepicker';
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";


export default class App extends Component<{}>{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      vibrate: false,
      date: new Date(),
      isShowDatePicker: false
    }
  }


  render(){
    var {date} = this.state
    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: "F5FCFF"
      }}>
        <Text>{date.getFullYear()}Y {date.getMonth() + 1}M {date.getDate()}D</Text>

        <Button
        title={'Press'}
        onPress={() => this.setState({ isShowDatePicker: !this.state.isShowDatePicker })} />
        <DateTimePickerModal
          isVisible={this.state.isShowDatePicker}
          mode="date"
          date={this.state.date}
          onConfirm={
            date=>{this.setState({date})}
          }
          onCancel={() => this.setState({ isShowDatePicker: !this.state.isShowDatePicker })}
          headerTextIOS='Please Select Date'
          confirmTextIOS='OK' />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to write the process in OnConfirm like this, but I can't do it.

```
      onConfirm={
        date=>{this.setState({date})},
        () => this.setState({ isShowDatePicker: !this.state.isShowDatePicker })
      }
```

This description only closes the window and does not set the time.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your `onConfirm` like this..This would close the modal

```
onConfirm={(data) => {
                this.setState({date})
                this.setState({ isShowDatePicker: false })
           }
```

Also your `onCancel` like this

```
onCancel={() => this.setState({ isShowDatePicker: false })}
```

Don't set the state to `!isShowDatePicker` as we know `onCancel` and `onConfirm` we need to close the modal..so set it to `false` rather than setting it to `!isShowDatePicker`

Also change your `Button` onPress to this

```
<Button
    title={'Press'}
    onPress={() => this.setState({ isShowDatePicker:true })} />
```

See working example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/date-time-format)